# Should I add an 'if' statement to jQuery that doesn't execute on certain pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to keep my code clean as possible and I am just wondering what would be the best way to go around this problem when it comes to best practices.

I have the following function:

```
  $('.car-hub-header-help, #assistance-overlay').click(function(){
    $('#new-car-hub, #new-car-offer').toggleClass('assistance-active');
    $('#pulman-assistance').toggleClass('pulman-assistance-active').css("top", fixedPositionCalculator);
    $('#assistance-overlay').toggleClass('assistance-overlay-active');
    $('#new-car').toggleClass('assistance-active-body');
    $('#new-car-offer-cta').toggleClass('assistance-active-cta');
  });
```

Now as you can see this function is very simple it just toggles classes based on a click event. One issue that I am having is that the element `new-car-offer-cta` is only on specific pages and it seems like this is bad practice to run that part of the function if the element isn't on some of my pages.

So I am just wondering if this would be better practice:

```
  $('.car-hub-header-help, #assistance-overlay').click(function(){
    $('#new-car-hub, #new-car-offer').toggleClass('assistance-active');
    $('#pulman-assistance').toggleClass('pulman-assistance-active').css("top", fixedPositionCalculator);
    $('#assistance-overlay').toggleClass('assistance-overlay-active');
    $('#new-car').toggleClass('assistance-active-body');

    var carOfferCta = $('#new-car-offer-cta');
    if (carOfferCta.length) {
      carOfferCta.toggleClass('assistance-active-cta');
    };
  });
```

So that part of the function wont run unless the element is on the page. I am just wondering what is classed as the best practice. Thanks

Comment: There's no "best practice" - if you have 100s of commands in the `if`, then yes, shortcut it, but the code provided gains nothing from the `if`.  

A better way (opinion) would be to turn it around and have toggleClass apply to a specific class only, and add that class to the items you want toggled by the click.  Then you don't need to change your code everytime you add a new element, just add the class to that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery already does that check for you, if the selector inside `$()` doesn't match any elements, the functions you chain to it won't do anything (not even produce an error). So there's really no need to check explicitly. With these exceptions:

- if you want it to be absolutely obvious to anybody reading your code, that the element you're trying to create won't exist on every page that uses your script or
- if you want to do a bunch of different things in your if statement,

then it makes sense to explicitly write `if ($element.length)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against doing the check at all. The beauty of jQuery is that you usually don't have to know whether your selector selects 0, 1 or more elements, the methods will just work (even if working is doing nothing at all).

If you start adding these checks everywhere, you're just coupling different parts of your logic more tightly together.

(That's also why I usually prefer not to use id selectors, but select based on classes instead. If then your html changes and e.g. your jQuery code needs to act on more elements, you don't need to change anything in the structure of your page, just apply the right classes.)

Answer (score -1):

It's better to ask if the element's val is !=undefined, rather than asking for it's length, since that way you're assuming it does exist on the page. You can add the length check right after asking for the element's existence, I usually do as follows:

`if($('#new-car-offer-cta').val() != undefined && $('#new-car-offer').val().length > 0){
      //do something
}`

Comment: He's not checking the length of a val, but of the result of a jQuery selector. If there are no matches, this will be an empty collection (with length 0), so his check was fine.